# Is this a known bug in `xsane`?

Tags: 16.04, scanner, gimp

I'm trying to use GIMP 2.8.15 with `xsane` 0.999 to control my ancient (built in 1998) Agfa Arcus 1200 scanner in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (AMD FX8350, 8 cores/threads, 16 GB RAM).

I've got everything installed and working, and the scanner hardware is okay.  I can scan negatives over the full bed with the trial version of Vuescan, but when I try to use `xsane` either stand-alone or as a GIMP plug-in, in "transparency" mode I'm limited to an area about 13x18 cm (5x7 inches) in the upper left portion of the scan bed.  I can scan the full bed in "flatbed" (reflective original) mode, so (as far as I can tell) it's not a problem with the `sane` backend.

I've verified all the `xsane` settings against the the helpfile; setting to "8.5x11 inches" scan area reports correctly in the main `xsane` window, but changes to 5x7 inches or 13x18 cm (approximately) whenever I try to initiate either a preview or a scan.  Scan resolution setting to 300 ppi (from the 1200 ppi I normally use, which is the scanner's optical resolution) changes nothing other than the pixel count in the resolution display.  The preview window button is set to "full size".

Since the alternative is to either spend money on the Pro version of Vuescan, or spend much more money on a new scanner (minimum around $800 for one that will scan 4x5 film, which I shoot), I have a strong interest in getting `xsane` to behave.  I've looked at `xscanimage` (requires compile to install, I'm not knowledgeable enough to do that) and `quiteinsane` (command line only), but I need this to work as a GIMP plugin, as designed.

What am I missing, or how can I fix this?

Comment: This may not be the answer you are looking for, but if Vuescan works, why not buy it? A quick look at their web page says there is a 30 day money back guarantee and the Pro version is on sale. I have an older scanner too (Epson) and this looks like a viable solution to allow me to use it again.

Comment: @Syd Actually, a very reasonable question.  The answer is, I think, reasonable too: it's a month's film and chemistry budget.  I have free software, already installed, that *should* do what Vuescan does (only better, in terms of importing directly into GIMP) -- buying Vuescan seems like buying a new lawnmower because the old is out of gas or the blade needs sharpened.

Comment: To close voter: how is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS a development version of Ubuntu?  It's not even End Of Life; it's supported until this time next year, or so.

Comment: You mean you DON'T go and buy a new mower every time you run out of gas?? ;p  As for xsane - which frontend are you using? According to the xsane site, there are a bunch that might work better.  http://www.sane-project.org/sane-frontends.html

Comment: @Syd I'm using `xsane`.  It's the only one with that name on that page (I've never seen that page before, I just installed xsane from repository because I found that GIMP needed it to acquire images from my scanner).

Comment: Can you scan from within GIMP? Is there an option to do so? What version of GIMP are you using? I believe 2.8 actually installs, while 2.10 is a Snap (which are much harder to work with because they are virtual apps with no accessible config files).  Also, one of those gui frontends on the xsane page might fix the sizing issue.

Comment: @Syd `xsane` *is* how GIMP handles direct scanning.  It's the only `sane` front end I know of that acts as a plugin for GIMP.  FWIW, I'm using GIMP 2.8.15, but `xsane` has the same problem if invoked from menu or command line.

Comment: I apologise. I misread your last comment.

Comment: @Syd Apparently `xscanimage` also works as a GIMP plug-in; I guess I need to figure out how to install it to see if this problem is in the `sane` backend or something specific to `xsane`.

Comment: xscanimage (has download link) - https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xscanimage.1.html

sane documenttation (has install to GIMP instructions) - http://www.sane-project.org/man/xscanimage.1.html

Comment: @syd I'll look at that when i get home.  I think that's the same "compile your own" I already found.  I'm a user, not a developer -- having to compile stuff to use it is outside my comfort zone.

Comment: No compiling. The download is a file that you put into the GIMP plugin folder (something like ~/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/)

Comment: @Syd There is no actual program download for xscanimage binary (or even source).  The .gz you pointed to only contains a description or readme text-only file.

Comment: If the item in the tarball says xscanimage.1 then that is the file to place in your ~/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins folder.

Comment: @Syd I haven't found `xscanimage.1` -- I'll look again when I'm at home.

Comment: @Syd The `xscanimage.1` inside the .gz file is the contents of the man page in something like laTex format.  There's no program of any kind.